# Get variable value, javascript firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have one problem. I am trying to get value from one variable but I can't do this. If somebody can help I will appreciate that. This is my code.

```
function getInfo() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("db_storage/");
    var info = 0;

    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        info = snapshot.val().length;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });

    return info;
}

var info = getInfo();
alert(info);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. My guess is that your `info` isn't what you expect. Please explain what you're getting, and what you think it should be. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints on phrasing your question.

Comment: I am getting zero(0). I need to get number of elements in array(rows in my database). snapshot.val().length return this number, but I can't use this number outside of function.

Comment: This is (probably) because your `info = snapshot.val().length` is happening in an *asynchronous* callback. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment above.

The `ref.on("value"...)` is an event listener that gets triggered when the 'value' event is dispatched by the database ref. When your code runs it goes (roughly speaking) into `getInfo()`, attaches the event listener, then proceeds to your last line *without waiting for the 'value' event*.

To hook things up, pass a callback function as follows.

```
function getInfo(callback) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("db_storage/");

    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var info = snapshot.val().length;
        return callback(info);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code);
        return callback(0);
     });
}

getInfo(function(info) {
    alert(info);
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks for help and for explanations. It works.

Comment: Would you mind accepting this answer then -- thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers